# Dart - Cannot create toJSON method

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `User` object and I want to be able to decode it from JSON and convert it to a JSON as well. `fromJSON()` method works fine but when I try to add `toJSON()` method the compiler gets mad. Any idea on this?

```
Missing type arguments for map literal.  Try adding an explicit type, or remove implicit-dynamic from your analysis options file.
```

Here is my `User` model

```
class User {
  int id;
  String userName;

  User({this.id, this.userName});

  factory User.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    return User(
        id: int.parse(json['id'].toString()),
        userName: json['user_name'].toString());
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() =>
      {
        'id': id,
        'user_name': userName,
      };
}
```

Comment: Can you add the part of the code where you're calling `toJson()`;

Comment: @AkoraIng.DKB I get this error on method declaration so I cannot even proceed to that step

Comment: I can't seem to spot where the problem is. I copied the exact code into DartPad and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per error message, you have `implicit-dynamic` forbidden in your static analysis settings. You have 2 options:

1. Check your `analysis_options.yml` file, look for `implicit-dynamic: false` line and delete it (or change to `true`).
2. Add explicit type to the map in your code:

```dart
Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => <String, dynamic>{
      'id': id,
      'user_name': userName,
    };
```

I would go with the second way because implicit dynamics can lead to some subtle errors, and it's better to forbid them.

Answer (score 0):

remove analysis_options.yaml or enable implicit-dynamic.